# Can a Seafaring race attack the land from a sea or lake region?

Tags: small-world

As a seafaring race if I conquer the lake in the middle of the map, do the regions adjacent to the lake become vulnerable to my attack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can attack these new adjacent regions after conquering the seas or lake. The Seafaring [rules](http://static.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_en.pdf) state that the seas and lake are considered empty regions for you:

> **Seafaring**
>
> As long as your Seafaring race is active, you may conquer
>   the Seas and the Lake, considering them as 3 empty Regions. You keep
>   these Regions even once you go into Decline, and continue scoring for
>   them for as long as you have tokens there. Only Seafaring races may
>   occupy the Seas and the Lake

Since they are just regions, the rules for subsequent conquests apply:

> The active player can repeat this process to conquer as many new
>   Regions as he wishes during his turn, provided he has enough Race
>   tokens left to accomplish these successive conquests. Each of the
>   newly conquered Regions must be adjacent to (i.e. sharing a border
>   with) a Region already occupied by his active Race tokens, unless
>   permitted otherwise by his Race and Special Power combo.

Go forth and conquer!